# How to run SOAP services using jasmine framework using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap, jasmine, jasmine-node

I am using jasmine-node framework for my API automation. I am able to run REST services and able to get the result using node-fetch or http. But in my project there is also requirement for testing SOAP services. How can I do that? Is there any specific module for that. Please advise

Answer (score 0):

[Sinon](https://sinonjs.org) can be used to mock objects in JavaScript unit testing.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to make soap request have a look at this module in npm 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap
Maybe this will help you to make soap request in Node.js env.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred SOAP package is

https://github.com/strongloop/strong-soap (backed by IBM)

```
soap.createClient(wsdlpath, options, function(err, client) {
  // client has all the functions i.e., client.Login()
});
```